# converting hebrew books

Tags: kindle, ebook-readers, kindle-paperwhite

I have a hebrew word file, which I want to read on my kindle. I tried converting it to epub/azw3, and all went well, except for the directions of the book. Hebrew is supposed to be read right to left, but in the display of the book on the device, the book was read from the left side (like english). How do I change the directions of the file?

Comment: What did you use to convert it?

Comment: calibre... it converted the file, but again, the directions were wrong